# I want to store some credentials in the session at the time when server lifts in Sails

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sails.js, sails-postgresql, sails-redis

I am using Sails and Postgres and I want to save some credentials in the session at the start-up of server.
Kindly help me. How can I do this, and is there any possibilities that it may give some error just because of database connectivity with the application. I am using connect-redis"~1.4.5".

Comment: But session starts for each user when he enters site, not when server starts. So what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You do have the option of utilising the bootstrap.js file. Essentially this runs code you define during the lifting process of sails. For instance you could use this to pre-populate a test database or in your case to authenticate a "test" user and store the person within a session.

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/bootstrap-js

Documentation is linked above.